# getchar() is taking a char that was already entered

Tags: c, input

I have the following `for` loop for filling a two-dimensional array:

```c
for(i = 0; i < N/*(header macro)*/; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        printf("Please enter a value for a cell at index (%d, %d)\n", i, j);
        mat[i][j] = getchar() - '0';
    }
```

so what I expect is for the program to ask me for each index what is the value I want to enter. but when I run the program,  the program stops and waits for me to enter a char only after it skipped one index. so the console is something like this:

```
Please enter a value for a cell at index (0, 0)
0
Please enter a value for a cell at index (0, 1)
Please enter a value for a cell at index (0, 2)
1
Please enter a value for a cell at index (0, 3)
Please enter a value for a cell at index (0, 4)
1
(...)
```

Why does the program skip a char?

Comment: It doesn't skip a character. It reads a number. Then it reads the newline character. Note that `getchar` won't work at all if you're trying to read numbers greater than 9.

Comment: Well, there's that char `'\n'` that marks the end of the line when you press enter. `getchar()` reads any char, including white space; it may not be suitable to what you want to do. (Your approach will read only single-digit numbers.)

Comment: I assume you pressed enter after you input the first char. "Enter Key" itself is an char as well.